# How to skip Rails validations when using ActiveStorage "attach"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I have a model with a Logo as attachment.

**When user uploads an image, the validation `name` and `url` validation should be skipped.**

The `validates :logo` should be still validated

Is this possible, and if yes: How?

Thank you!

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one_attached :logo do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :thumbnail, resize_to_fit: [100, 100]
  end

  validates :logo, content_type: %w[image/png image/jpg image/jpeg]

  # following line should be skipped
  validates_presence_of :name, :url # this should be skipped when attaching an image !!!

end

# MyModelController
# That is my current controller action

  # PATCH /shops/update_logo
  def update_logo
    if logo_params[:logo].present?
      logo = logo_params[:logo]
      if logo && @current_user.my_model.logo.attach(logo)
        render json: @current_user, status: :ok
      else
        render json: @current_user.my_model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity, error: @current_user.my_model.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
      end
    else
      render json: { error: "no image selected" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hack with [`:on`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on)

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :url, presence: true, on: :not_attachment
  validates :logo, content_type: %w[image/png image/jpg image/jpeg]
end
```

```rb
my_model.name = my_model.url = nil
my_model.logo.attach(logo)
my_model.valid? # => true
```

```rb
my_model.name = my_model.url = nil
my_model.save(context: :not_attachment)
my_model.valid? # => false
```

Comment: Thank you @mechnicov. I didn't knew `:context`:-) That works for `.save`. If someone stumbles over this issue too: I solved `.update` (which ends up in `wrong argument errors`) with a `my_model.assign_attributes(my_params); my_model.save(context: :not_attachment)`.